# How can I make this bash xautolock script works?

Tags: bash, archlinux, i3

H_i guys, I'm running Arch with i3 as WM, i3lock works fine when manually executed via keybinding, xautolock is ofc installed and the script is launched at startup ( when trying to manually launch it I get this message : " xautolock is already running (PID 1302)" but my screen never automatically locks

Here is the script :

```
#!/bin/sh

exec xautolock -detectsleep \
  -time 3 -locker "i3lock -d -c 000000" \
  -notify 30 \
  -notifier "notify-send -u critical -t 10000 -- 'LOCKING screen in 30 seconds'"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a backslash missing after `-detectsleep`?

Comment: Tested right now , doesn't change anything

Comment: Please edit and update your question with your minor edits to the script so that it's current. Otherwise, the missing backslash will be blatant.